# Sending multiple intents from one activity to another in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I am working on a student timetable android app project where i should set alarm for a particular class of particular day of particular time slot.For eg. Operating systems is on monday at 11AM then alarm should be set before few minutes.For this i need to send 3 intents from one to another activity for sending day,timeslot and subject name.I am having some problem with the following snippet of code while trying to send the intents.

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {


                        String subject = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("subject"));
                        String day = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("day"));

                        String slot1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("7:30-9:10AM"));    
                        String slot2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("9:20-11:00AM"));
                        String slot3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("11:10-12:50PM"));
                        String slot4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("1:40-3:20PM"));
                        String slot5 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("3:30-5:00PM"));

                    TableRow tr1=new TableRow(viewtimetable.this);

                                tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));     

                            TextView b=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);

                                b.setText(day);
                                b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b.setTextSize(15);
                                tr1.addView(b);


                               TextView b1=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b2=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b3=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b4=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);
                               TextView b5=new TextView(viewtimetable.this);


                                b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b1.setTextSize(15);
                                b1.setTextColor(Color.RED);


                                b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b2.setTextSize(15);


                                b3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b3.setTextSize(15);


                                b4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b4.setTextSize(15);


                                b5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b5.setTextSize(15);


                                if(day.equals("Friday"))
                                {

                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                        b1.setText(slot1);
//Here's the main scene.I only want to send the intent if the above condition satisfies.
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Day",day);
    intent.putExtra("Subject",subject);

startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }

                                else if(day.equals("Monday"))
                                {
                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }



                                else if(day.equals("Tuesday"))
                                {

                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }


                                else if(day.equals("Wednesday"))
                                {

                                    if(slot1 != null){ 
                                    b1.setText(slot1);
                                    }
                                    if(slot2 != null)
                                    {
                                        b2.setText(slot2);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot3 != null)
                                    {
                                        b3.setText(slot3);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot4 != null)
                                    {
                                        b4.setText(slot4);  
                                    }
                                    if(slot5 != null)
                                    {
                                        b5.setText(slot5);  
                                    }

                                 }


                                else if(day.equals("Thursday"))
                                    {

                                        if(slot1 != null){ 
                                        b1.setText(slot1);
                                        }
                                        if(slot2 != null)
                                        {
                                            b2.setText(slot2);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot3 != null)
                                        {
                                            b3.setText(slot3);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot4 != null)
                                        {
                                            b4.setText(slot4);  
                                        }
                                        if(slot5 != null)
                                        {
                                            b5.setText(slot5);  
                                        }

                                     }



                                else if(day.equals("Saturday"))
                                        {

                                            if(slot1 != null){ 
                                            b1.setText(slot1);
                                            }
                                            if(slot2 != null)
                                            {
                                                b2.setText(slot2);  
                                            }
                                            if(slot3 != null)
                                            {
                                                b3.setText(slot3);  
                                            }
                                            if(slot4 != null)
                                            {
                                                b4.setText(slot4);  
                                            }
                                            if(slot5 != null)
                                            {
                                                b5.setText(slot5);  
                                            }

                                         }

                                  tr1.addView(b1);  
                                  tr1.addView(b2);
                                  tr1.addView(b3);
                                  tr1.addView(b4);
                                  tr1.addView(b5);
                                  tv.addView(tr1);
```

**Problem**

If i do like above,the exception it generates is

```
couldn't read row 0,col -1 from CursowWindow.Make sure the cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

**Question**

What should i modify in the code snippet so that i can send the intent to AlarmReceiver.class activity and can retrieve there using

```
String day =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("Day");
String subject = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Subject");
```

**PS**

I also tried using `SharedPreferences` but the same exception is thrown.

**Solution**

It was stupid but in my query i didn't project a column of the database which i am using in the code.Hence the exception.

Comment: as in log means cursor is empty so make sure data is available in cursor before accessing

Comment: The cursor was not empty.There was a silly problem in my query.Btw Thanks.Please check my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is due to some, perhaps more than one, of the calls:

```
c.getColumnIndex(columnName)
```

These methods return -1 if there is no column named `columnName`. Consequentely, `c.getString(-1)` rises an Exception because `-1` is not a valid column. Make sure that those columns names are really present in your database/ContentProvider and in your projection during your query.

Comment: Absolutely right.Although every mentioned columns were present in the database ,"subject" column was not being projected during my query.Hence the exception.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think your cursor is empty. 
Try this :

```
c.moveToFirst();
while(c.moveToNext()) {
Log.d("ClassName","Cursor is not empty");
rest of code
}
```

Comment: When the cursor is empty, there will be 0 rows and 0 columns in the cursor. So I think this answer is correct. There is no point of down vote.

Comment: Well the cursor was not empty.The query which i used was a little bit less than required.Please see my edit.